# Circular function import

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to do the following in python 2.6.

```
my_module.py:-
    from another_module import another_factory

    def my_factory(name):
        pass

another_module.py:-
    from my_module import my_factory

    def another_factory(name):
        pass
```

Both modules in the same folder.

It gives me the error:

```
Error: cannot import name my_factory
```

Comment: Please, show the structure of the folders and modules of your project

Comment: Can you show the error when you try the first method? And an example of how you try to use the function.

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly happens? "Not working" is not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Does `my_module` import `another_module` and viceversa?

Comment: @ikaros45 Yes, is this possible in python?

Comment: You should not change the title of the question... it gets confusing for the newcomers. And if you consider the answer is good enough, tick it! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As seen from the comments, you are trying to do a circle import which is impossible.

If in your module A you try to import something from the module B, and when loading the module B (to satisfy this dependency) you are trying to import something from the module A, you are where you started and you got a circle import: A needs B and B needs A!!, it is somehow like saying that A needs A, which is quite unlogic.

For instance:

```
# moduleA
from moduleB import functionB
...
```

So the interpreter tries to load the moduleB, which looks like the following:

```
# moduleB
from moduleA import functionA
...
```

And goes back to the moduleA, which tries again to import B, and, etc. Therefore python just raises the error and stops the insanity for a greater good.

Dependencies don't work like this. Define what module needs the other one, and just do a simple import. In your example, it seems that `another_module` needs `my_module`, so change `my_module` and eliminate the dependency on `another_module`.

If both modules actually need each other, it is a clear sign that they belong to the same logical concept, and should be merged.

PD: in some cases to avoid huge files, you can split a logical unit in two, and to avoid the circle dependencies, you write your imports inside of the functions (which are not executed at load time), so that there is not a circle. This is however in general something to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is... do you consider each file as a *module* or are they part of a *package* ?

Trying to import *modules* outside a *package* is sometimes painful. You should rather build a package by simply creating an empty **__init__.py** module in the directory. Though, if you have

```
__init__.py
my_module.py
another_module.py
```

If you have te following function in **my_module.py**,

```
def my_factory(x):
    return x * x
```

You should be able to access the *my_factory()* function from **another_module.py** by writing this :

```
from my_module import my_factory
```

But, if you don't have the **__init__.py** file/module, the import function will be (somehow) lost and will only use the **sys.path** for searching other modules. You may then add the following lines (before the *import*) in the **another_module.py** file :

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser('.')))
```

You may also use the various packages available to help importing modules, like **imp** or **import_file** (see the documentation). Or you can decide to use **load_source** (also see the doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html)